# Could not load file or assembly Topshelf

Tags: c#, dependencies, topshelf

I'm having trouble starting a C# project as a service. When I manually try to execute the file, I get the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Topshelf, Version=3.3.154.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b800c4cfcdeea87b' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>           at NFDataImporter.Program.Main(String[] args)

I've already checked the Topshelf dependency in Visual Studio, and it is set as a NuGet dependency. The project is then built via TeamCity, which has a full functional NuGet Install step that satisfyingly returns:

```
 [14:53:31][restore] All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

However, the above error still persists, and I'm at my wit's end here.

Can somebody  please help me with this?

Comment: Did you check whether the DLL is being copied to the output directory?

Answer (score 1):

You could check how you have referenced the assembly in your project. If you have specified version in the reference, see it matches the package.config file.

You could use a binding redirect if you expect the assembly at runtime could be a different version.

Also, look at the teamcity build logs, see if it copying all the assemblies to the output directory

Comment: Also have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761322/nuget-not-restoring-packages-on-build, your packages might not be actually getting restored correctly

Answer (score 0):

For dotnet6 i had ommited the runtime folder inside the bin folder when i copied the exe to my service deployment folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).